# All white text when coding with Java in VSC

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I recently noticed that when coding with java in VSC, all text is white. With html, css and js, I don't have this problem. What do I have to do to make it colorful again?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Comment: @PM77-1 - your advice seems to be to change a global setting, but the question indicates that the problem is language specific.  I don't know VSC.  Is there a similar set of settings specific to each language?

Comment: @Steve - my advice is to ***verify*** that correct settings are selected. Including, specifically for Java.

Comment: You say "again".  Were you getting colored text and then all of a sudden you weren't?  Do you have a Java extension installed, and if so, which one?  Are other language-specific features, like code completion, working, or is Java support completely gone?  If you don't have a Java extension installed, that should explain this and @geekTechnique's answer should help fix that.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I actually didn't put too much thought into the word "again" when I contributed my answer. You pose a very good question.

Comment: Check vs-code settings: " ctrl + , "

Comment: as it seem sit was a bug with the java Language Support by Red Hat which has already been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a language support extension for java.

Go to your extensions tab in VSC on the left menu and search for "java". The 3rd result as of writing this post is "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat
redhat.java".

[image]

I recommend you install that one, but you could use a different java language support extension. This one includes java linting and syntax highlighting, which is what I believe you're asking for.